# Parabola fitting with two given points and a cost function

Tags: algorithm, math, curve-fitting

Suppose that there is a parabola `Y = aX^2 + bX + c`, and it might be rotated as follow:

```
X = x.sin(phi) + y.cos(phi)
Y = x.cos(phi) - y.sin(phi)
phi = rotation angle
```

We wish to fit it on a border (e.g. inner border of an eyelid, figure below). The problem is that how we can change the parabola in each iteration such that it minimizes a cost function. We know that the parabola can be in different rotation and its origin may vary in the search region. Note that the there are two given points which the fitted parabola should passes through them (e.g. the white squares in fig below). So, In each iteration we can compute `a`, `b` and `c` by the two given points and the origin point (three equations and three variables).
The question is how we can reach the goal in minimum iteration (not to test all the possibilities, i.e. all angles and all positions in the search region).

[image]

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Still off-topic here. This a question of mathematics, not programming. That you MAY choose to implement it eventually in some language is not relevant. You are still trying to define the problem you wish to solve, so off-topic.

Comment: Again, what is the cost function the solution is supposed to minimize?

Comment: @ Joni, Thanks for your comment. We have a cost function and it returns a value close to zero, if the parabola fit to the inner border of the eyelid (see fig above).

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question at all. Is the cost function convex? Does it have many local minima or a single global maximum? What stops you from using general optimization algorithms like gradient descent?

Answer (score 1):

@woodchips: I think this is a programming problem, and he asked a solution for the implementation.I definitely disagree with you.

A possible solution would be to first search along the vertical line which is orthogonal to the line between the two given points. And also you can vary the angle  in this interval. As the nature of your problem (the border of eyelid), you can limit the angle variation between -pi/4 and pi/4. After you find the minimum cost for a position in this vertical line, you can search along the horizontal line and do similar tasks.

Comment: @ codeplusplus, thanks for your answer. Your solution seems not bad, but the problem is, after finding the min cost for a point in vertical line, there is no guarantee that that point remains as optimal, if we change its horizontal position.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regression to fit a parabola to several points in the target shape?  Then you could use which ever algorithm you wanted to get an approximate solution.  Newton's method converges pretty fast.  The optimization here is on the coefficients in the approximate parabolas.